# Octave: How to correctly make string as a condition?

Tags: function, if-statement, octave, octave-gui

I was trying the `if` test for the first time, well actually so does with function.

Here's the script:

```
function trial()
  I = input("f INPUT > Manually input frequency value? (yes/no):");
  if I = "yes"; 
    f = input("Please input the frequency value : \n") 
  elseif I = "no";
    f = randi([100 1000],5,5)
  endif
O = 2*pi*f;
fprintf("%.2f \n",O); 
plot(f,O);
xlabel("Frequency");
ylabel("Angular Frequency");
end
    f INPUT > Manually input frequency value? (yes/no):"no"
    Please input the frequency value :
```

There are 2 things that I don't understand:

1. Why do I have to write the condition with quotation marks? (i.e `"yes"` not `yes` or `"no"` not `no`).
2. Why the `'no'` condition ran the input command when it should've been `randi`?

Can someone show me how it should be done?

Answer (score 1):

`I = "yes"` assigns the string "yes" to the variable `I`. To make a comparison, use `==` like this: `I == "yes"`. But this comparison will only work if the two strings are the same length, and will return an array, not a single equality value. Use `strcmp` to compare strings: `if strcmp(I, "yes")`.

The `input` function parses what the user types, so that typing `3` will result in the number `3`, not the string `"3"`. If you add a second input argument like this: `input("prompt","s")` then it will not parse the input, and return a string. The user will then be able to type `no`. See [the docs](https://octave.org/doc/v4.4.1/Terminal-Input.html).